# How to affect only one property when receving object after http get call

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

In my angular app I have an object like this

```
export class Article {
  id: number;
  author: number;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  date: Moment;
  readingTime: number;
  draft: boolean;

  constructor(obj: Partial<Article>) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
    this.date = moment(this.date);
  }
}
```

And as you see there is a property author:number which in fact is an object but i'm using only Id  when I make http call to post articles . When I get articles I receive the object with all values to null except of id. And I need this id to be attached to the property author but insted the hole object is taking the place instead of number

I need to do something like this , but article.author.id (id is not recognized as property of number property)

```js
updateArticle(): void {
    this.register(this.articleService.getArticles()
      .pipe(tap(articles => {
        articles.map(article => {
          if(typeof article.author === 'object')
         return {...article , author:article.author.id}
        })
      }))
      .subscribe(articles => this.articles = articles));
  }
```

Comment: I think you call the http like this: this.httpClient.get<Article>().... right?

Comment: tap is meant for side effects you should use map if you want to alter the values. see tap documentation https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap.

Answer (score 0):

how about if you change `author` type to

`author: number | { id: number };`

Comment: will solve the problem (AFAIK) but try to add some explanation why this solves the problem.

Comment: It doesn't help. One solution is to use number | any ; but I wouldn't to put any as type in typescript. I think I have to declare a class apart

Comment: Typescrpit typing has nothing to do with actual values at runtime. Type declarations will never change the actual value.